# Tkinter - Changing the list in Option Menu

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, optionmenu

Is there a way to manipulate the List displayed by the OptionMenu in respect to what the user has currently selected?

For example, let's say I have a list - `["A","B","C"]`.

If the user currently selected `A` then if he clicks the optionmenu with `A` currently selected, what he will see in the list is not the original list but only `B` and `C`.

If he switches his answer from, let's say, `A` to `B`, then now, he will only see `A` and `C` in the OptionMenu.

And the same will follow if he chose `B` or `C`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The OptionMenu widget is a button that shows a dropdown menu when pressed. You might do better to use a ttk.Combobox instead as that is a more modern UI element and you can very simply configure the values configuration item.

You can configure the attached menu at runtime. You access the menu using `optionmenu['menu']` and you can then query items on the menu `optionmenu['menu'].entrycget(0, 'label')` or use `entryconfigure` to modify the items. Or you can delete items `optionmenu['menu'].delete(index)` and add new items. See the [menu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm) documentation for hints on manipulating the menu entries.